# How to add Magento database in AWS?

Tags: magento2, aws

I am new with AWS. i was able to setup magento ecommerce store using E2 Instances, I am having issues with the full installation (the database aspects ), i will be glad if anybody can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can simply edit database credentials in your env file

Comment: where or how do i get the env file